# MIPS pipeline cycles

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline

I'm trying to understand how the following MIPS code in a pipelined datapath would execute.

```
  lw  $4, 100($2)
  sub $6, $4, $3
  add $2, $3, $5
```

The MIPS instruction set has 5 stages (fetch, decode, execute, memory access, write back).

The answer is: 8 cycles but I'm having difficulty understanding why. Here is what the pipeline could look like (incomplete).

```
  C F   D   E  M   WB
  1 lw
  2 sub lw       
  3 add sub lw
  4 add sub  x  lw
  5     add sub    lw
  6         add sub
  7
  8
```

Questions: Why the x (stall?) at 4 and 5? How do I come up with the cycles including 7 and 8?

Comment: The stalls are presumably because the instruction needs the result of the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'd need to have the full datapath details from your textbook or assignment (I assume) to be sure. Here are some possibilities:

- The `sub` instruction stalls for 2 cycles before entering Execute, because it needs to wait for the `lw` result to finish Writeback
- The `add` instruction stalls until `sub` is finished Writeback, again because it's waiting for a result.

The detail that's relevant to both of these possibilities is when results from a given instruction become available to later dependent instructions. Does your datapath have register bypass of some sort? Are results in Writeback available the same cycle, or the next?

Comment: I'm sorry, the question only reads "consider executing the following code on the MIPS pipelined datapath" followed by the instructions without any previous details. I think you are right about sub waiting for lw to finish Writeback, though I don't fully understand that part yet. I do know that the answer is "8 cycles", so whichever scenario is the most plausible?